# Viewing function arguments in WinDbg

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, windbg

I'm reverse engineering something. I'd like to view a nice print-out of arguments being passed to various system functions in WinDbg. Kind of like OllyDbg does.
How do I do this without symbols ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot view it like ollydbg / Immunity debugger. But you can retrieve arguments from stack manually. You have to check the API reference in MSDN and retrieve augments from stack.

As an example, to get arguments of MessageBoxW() you can set a break point at MessageBoxW().

```
0:002> g
(9e0.91c): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=7efa9000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=76f6f8ea esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=76ee000c esp=00f3ff5c ebp=00f3ff88 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
76ee000c cc              int     3
0:005> bp user32!MessageBoxW
0:005> g
Breakpoint 0 hit
eax=00000001 ebx=00000000 ecx=002a2fc6 edx=00000000 esi=002b7f00 edi=00000003
eip=749ffd3f esp=000cf608 ebp=000cf624 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
USER32!MessageBoxW:
749ffd3f 8bff            mov     edi,edi
```

Now when the break point get hit, you can get them from stack. MessageBoxW() accepts 4 arguments. So we dump 5 stack elements from stack.

```
0:000> dd esp L5
000cf608  01001fc4 000806aa 002b7f00 002a3074
000cf618  00000040
```

Where **0x01001fc4** is the return address, where MessageBoxW will return. And next 4 pointers are arguments passed to MessageBoxW(). Now you can dump them accordingly.

```
0:000> du 002b7f00
002b7f00  "Cannot find "foo""
0:000> du 002a3074
002a3074  "Notepad"
```

Hope it will help :)